# AWS Lambda JavaCompiler instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

In an AWS Lambda Java 8 Function, is it possible to get an instance of  `SystemJavaCompiler`? Here's a snippet:

```
final File root = new File("/tmp");    
final File sourceFile = new File(root, type.getSourceFilename());

sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), templateString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
```

I'm attempting to dynamically compile source code in a Lambda and `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` throws a `NullPointerException`. This works great locally. I was hoping to avoid deploying an EC2 instance to benefit from the resource savings of Lambda.

Comment: Maybe there is no SDK, JRE only

Comment: I just realized this as well :(

Comment: @Antoniossss submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is no SDK, JRE only.